# Issues with Pooled Connection, ActiveMQ 5.14.3, JMS 2.0, Karaf 4.2.0

Tags: jms, osgi, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

I have a scenario where I cannot switch to Artemis right now. And following up with several posts, I understood that it gets tricky for ActiveMQ to communicate with JMS 2.0.

Because of some limitations in Jolokia api ([Is it possible to retrieve more than 400 messages from ActiveMQ queue via Jolokia API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708890/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-more-than-400-messages-from-activemq-queue-via-joloki)), I switched to JMS API to browse my queues as suggested in the comments. This works perfectly fine and gave the intended results when its ran as an standalone application, as I have included activemq-client as one of the dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.12.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I tried deploying similar implementation in Karaf with the same dependency, by creating connection factory as:

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory( 
                    "tcp://localhost:61616");
```

this failed because: 
1. activemq-client requires JMS 1.x 
2. my karaf container has JMS 2.0

Thus, I opted to use my pooled connection factory with `javax.jms-api/2.0` as JMS api dependency in the osgi bundle as:

e.g. my blueprint configuration; where `jms/consumer` is already available in the service registry

```xml
<reference id="jmsConnectionFactory" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"
 filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=jms/consumer)" availability="mandatory" />

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

A fragment of my code in creating the connection is as:

```java
brokerConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection(); 
session = this.createSession(brokerConnection); 
brokerConnection.start();
```

until this point, brokerConnection and session are not null.

```java
Queue queue = session.createQueue("test.queue"); 
queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue);
```

From this point on, I get a NullPointerException as:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createQueue(ActiveMQSession.java:1335) 
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.createQueue(PooledSession.java:197) 
at test.mbean.getBrokerEntries(BrokerMBean.java:142) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275) 
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112) 
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46) 
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237) 
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138) 
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252) 
at javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:405) 
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) 
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) 
at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:98) 
at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:40) 
at org.jolokia.handler.JsonRequestHandler.handleRequest(JsonRequestHandler.java:89) 
at org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerExecutorLocal.handleRequest(MBeanServerExecutorLocal.java:109) 
at org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerHandler.dispatchRequest(MBeanServerHandler.java:159) 
at org.jolokia.backend.LocalRequestDispatcher.dispatchRequest(LocalRequestDispatcher.java:99) 
...
```

I am not sure what went wrong here. Any inputs would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: ActiveMQ JMS client doesn't support JMS 2.0 so mixing code that might be attempting to use said API is likely to be the issue

Comment: you are right. At the moment, I chose to get rid of components relying on JMS 2.0. Again back to JMS 1.x and it works as intended. I had posted this question in ActiveMQ user forum(http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Invoking-JMS-API-with-JMS-2-0-ActiveMQ-and-osgi-karaf-td4750301.html) as well. Someone suggested me to try out QPID JMS driver. Although I did not succeed in the first tryouts, I will try these sooner.